# Gaming PC HD/OS/Harware/Software Switch-a-Roo

Tags: dual-boot

**My rig**: *AMD FX-8320E 3.8ghz Eight-Core, GeForce GTX 
750-2gb, 16gb RAM, win10x64* (used to be 7 home prem. 
win10 is vista+8=puke)

I currently have a 1tb hd and came across a second 
1tb hd. The primary has win10x64 and I need to roll 
it back to win7x64 (I have a copy ready to deploy as well as ubuntu). 
With this second hard drive, I'd like to dedicate Linux to it and learn more about the OS cuz, duh.

There is about 300gb of data that I'd like to back up. Unfortunately, I only have a couple 8gb flash drives at the ready. Luckily, I have a secondary laptop if I need to get advice/drivers/google/youtube anything.

I don't have to report to work until monday. Plz halp :-) Thanks.

--LaRue

Comment: What is the question here? If it's about how to install Ubuntu, then the answer is kind of obvious: download Ubuntu, burn to DVD or USB, boot your machine from it and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question would be is; What's the best way to backup multiple ISO files (40+GB slices), format 1 of the hdd, deploy win7x64 on it and on the other, deploy a copy of ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

All this is a bit out of the AskUbuntu Purview, but generally:

- *Backup*: To backup a lot of data to ISOs, one can use [Mondo Rescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/) ([here are instructions to install it in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MondoMindi), its not just `apt-get install` but not too hard). Boot Ubuntu live CD (without installing) and use it to backup your data.
- *Installation order*: Install Windows first, and then Ubuntu - the Ubuntu installer will detect the Windows installation and will add an entry to allow you to choose to boot to Windows or Ubuntu when the machine starts. If You install Ubuntu first, then the Windows installation will clobber the Ubuntu boot loader and will not let you load it.
- *Format of harddive*: Don't worry about it - show the Ubuntu installer the drive you prepared for it, tell it to use the entire drive and accept the default format.

Comment: Thanks so much for the given feedback. Will keep you guys posted on progress.  Happy New Year!!!

Answer (score 0):

Only connect 1 had and Install windows 7. When it's done disconnect it and connect the disk that will have Ubuntu installed on it. Install Ubuntu and one that is done have both drives plugged in and then through boot options you'll be a lip so select which one the default boot to and which one you will need to Force boot. Doing it this method will allow you to do to use each operating system independently and not depend on the other for boot